# Cloud composer unstable UI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

The Airflow UI randomly fails to show up and a 503 google error message is shown. It's getting really hard and annoying to navigate the Airflow UI. Is this a known issue? After searching this for a long time, on the internet I did not get any leads.

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

I have attached the error message that I'm getting randomly. Hope this gets fixed.[image: Error Message]

Comment: Can you post the Stackdriver logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you happen to be trying to access the Airflow UI from Asia? This is a known issue for APAC users, and a remedy is coming soon. In the meantime, a workaround is to [deploy a self-managed webserver](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/deploy-webserver).